# Xcode 8.0, session expired when tried to login with Apple id

Tags: xcode, apple-id

Running through this probelm from yesterday. Not able to sign in with apple id from Xcode or iCloud. Somebody please help.

[image: Screen shot]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually this was an issue from Apple. I have contacted them over mail and they have fixed the issue in 24 hours.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable Two-factor authentication for Apple ID

[Read here how to do this](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204915)

Comment: Thanks, but iCloud login is also not working, to accomplish this!